# What does Spacy use to create vector representations?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, spacy

What is Spacy's built in method of creating vector representations?
I performed NLP on my corpus, and then used .similarity (cosine similarity) to map out documents that were "similar". However, I am unsure what method spacy uses to create vector representations. To my knowledge, I am thinking that it is probably word2vec skip-gram with negative sampling, however, I would like to be sure!

Comment: https://explosion.ai/blog/how-spacy-works

Answer (score 3):

Spacy's default English model uses [GloVe word embeddings](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) to compute the similarity between two words. You can find more information in the [SpaCy documentation](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/word-vectors-similarities).

Comment: Is this still true for the `en_core_web_md` and `en_core_web_lg` models?  Second link above forwards to https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#vectors-similarity which doesn't mention the specific embedding algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

For versions 3.4.0 and higher of SpaCy's English models (`en_core_web_md` and `en_core_web_lg`), the default word vectors are floret vectors pretrained on multiple datasets (Wikipedia, OpenSubtitles, WMT Newscrawl, OSCAR 21.09). The repository with the training details is: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-vectors-builder

Earlier versions of the English model vectors were GloVe vectors trained on the CommonCrawl dataset. In general (e.g. for other languages/versions), this information is listed in the model release notes in the [spacy-models](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases) repo.